# The ? (three way) Operator

Tags: java, operators, ternary-operator

First of all, apologies for the following question, i am new to java, i have taken the example from a book but it fails to completely explain itself.

I have been reading about the ? operator and how it functions and using the below as an example to learn from:

```
class Ternary {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, k;
        i = 10;
        k = i < 0 ? -i : i; // get absolute value of i
        System.out.print("Absolute value of ");
        System.out.println(i + " is " + k);

        i = -10
        k = i < 0 ? -i : i; //get absolute value of i
        System.out.print("Absolute value of ");
        System.out.println(i + " is " + k);
    }
}
```

I understand how the first part gives the result of 10.
But i cannot follow how the second part gives the result of 10?

Apologies if this is plainly obvious.

Comment: -(-i) = +i, normal math

Comment: `i = 10; -i => -10;` and `i = -10; -i => --10 => 10;` (So it's a [Math](http://www.mathsisfun.com/positive-negative-integers.html) question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional operator is used to decide which of two values to assign to a variable.

It takes the form:

type variableName = (boolean condition) ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;

In your case you have:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i, k;
    i = -10;
    k = i < 0 ? -i : i; //get absolute value of i
    System.out.print("Absolute value of ");
    System.out.println(i + " is " + k);
}
```

So, we are saying:

i < 0, well i is equal to -10 and is therefore less than 0. therefore the true condition is assigned, which has the value of -i.

Since -(-10) = -*-10 = 10 [i.e minus times minus is plus], the output is 10.

Answer (score 1):

Since the ternary operator evaluates `i < 0` in your following line of code:

```
k = i < 0 ? -i : i; //get absolute value of i
```

If true `k = -i`

else false `k = i`

And as the others mentionned, `-(-10) == 10`
And I believe this is the output you want since you are trying to get the absolute value of a number, so if it is negative, print out it's positive value.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation qcGold, that makes really good sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

A negative of a negative is a positive 0 - (-10) = 10

Answer (score 0):

i gets set to -10 and then k checks if i < 0, which it is.

Therefore it performs the first case:

k = -(-10) = 10

Answer (score 0):

when setting k, we have the condition

```
i < 0
```

followed by the ?, which asks "Is i less than 0. If it is, it will return the first result (-i), and if it is not it will return the second result (i).

It means the same thing as:

```
if (i < 0){
    k = -i;
else{
    k = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = -10
k = i < 0 ? -i : i;
```

is the same as

```
k = i < 0 ? -(-10) : i;
```

gives you +10

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
k = i < 0 ? -i : i
```

it's interpreted as

```
if(i < 0){
    k = -i;
} else {
    k = i;
}
```

So since -10 is < 0, the given expression returns -(-10), that is 10