# How to write nested ?: statements

Tags: java, syntax, nested, operators, ternary-operator

I would like to shorten my code by the use of the `?:` (if-else-then) comparative operator instead of using the traditional `if{}else{}` blocks that inconveniently tend to take over the screen. I was never taught about this operator, and I would greatly appreciate any help regarding how to nest multiple comparisons within one line.

This is the code that I would like to shorten:

```
if(y<0)
    y=0;
else
   if(y+h>s.getHeight())
        y = s.getHeight()-h;
```

I managed to condense each condition to this (not nested):

```
y = (y<0) ? 0 : y;
y = (y+h>s.getHeight()) ? s.getHeight()-h : y;
```

Is this the correct way to nest it?

```
y = (y<0) ? 0 : ((y+h>s.getHeight()) ? s.getHeight()-h : y);
```

Thank you!

EDIT: I was given a link to another post pertaining to the ?: operator. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676600/the-three-way-operator). However, my question has to do with nesting instead of just a simple if statement. Therefore, my question is not a duplicate of that post.

Comment: Shorter doesn't always mean more readable.

Comment: Yes, this should be right, if you really want to do it this way.

Comment: On the aside, does anyone know if the traditional if/else blocks compile the same way as this compact method? If not, which is more or less strenuous?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The ? (three way) Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676600/the-three-way-operator)

Comment: For the first line there is probably a Math.Max or Math.Min function you could use.  Your original code is probably the best of the three options.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct syntax but it's not readable.

You can check by yourself this in Java. Like this:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 5;
String s = (a < b) ? "Less than b" : (a > b) ? "More than b" : "Equal as b";
System.out.println(s);
```

But code is much more readable if you use if and if else statements. This ? and : is just for basic if statement. 
For example:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 5;
String s = (a == b) ? "Equal" : "Not equal"
System.out.println(s);
```

But even in this case, I would rather use if statement. I really don't like to see ? and : instead of if statement :)

Regards,
golobic

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly used ternary operator. However you could have avoided repeated method invocations for `s.getHeight()`.

```
y = y < 0 ? 0 : y+h > s.getHeight() ? s.getHeight() - h : y;
```

Use the `?: (ternary) operator` instead of an if-then-else statement if that makes code more readable.

ex. `result = someCondition ? value1 : value2`;

This can be nested further if value1, value2 are also ternary expressions.